# R devtools install error - installation of package 'curl' had non-zero exit status

Tags: r

All,

Banging my head up against a wall on this one.  I'm trying to install devtools for R on **Mac OSX 10.11.2**.  Using **R version 3.2.3**, installed via **homebrew** `brew install R`.  However, I get an error when the dependencies are installed for curl.  Here's the output when I try to install.packages('curl')

```
> install.packages('curl')
Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/3.2/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://rweb.crmda.ku.edu/cran/src/contrib/curl_0.9.5.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 261496 bytes (255 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 255 KB

* installing *source* package ‘curl’ ...
** package ‘curl’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Using PKG_CFLAGS=
Using PKG_LIBS=-lcurl
** libs
clang -I/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.2.3/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/include  -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/include  -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -g -O2  -c callbacks.c -o callbacks.o
clang -I/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.2.3/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/include  -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/include  -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -g -O2  -c curl.c -o curl.o
clang -I/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.2.3/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/include  -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/include  -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -g -O2  -c download.c -o download.o
clang -I/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.2.3/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/include  -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/include  -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -g -O2  -c escape.c -o escape.o
clang -I/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.2.3/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/include  -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/include  -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -g -O2  -c fetch.c -o fetch.o
clang -I/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.2.3/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/include  -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/include  -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -g -O2  -c form.c -o form.o
clang -I/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.2.3/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/include  -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/include  -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -g -O2  -c getdate.c -o getdate.o
clang -I/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.2.3/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/include  -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/include  -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -g -O2  -c handle.c -o handle.o
clang -I/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.2.3/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/include  -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/include  -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -g -O2  -c ieproxy.c -o ieproxy.o
clang -I/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.2.3/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/include  -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/include  -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -g -O2  -c init.c -o init.o
clang -I/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.2.3/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/include  -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/include  -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -g -O2  -c nslookup.c -o nslookup.o
clang -I/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.2.3/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/include  -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/include  -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -g -O2  -c utils.c -o utils.o
clang -I/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.2.3/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/include  -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/include  -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -g -O2  -c version.c -o version.o
clang -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.2.3/R.framework/Resources/lib -L/usr/local/opt/gettext/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o curl.so callbacks.o curl.o download.o escape.o fetch.o form.o getdate.o handle.o ieproxy.o init.o nslookup.o utils.o version.o -L/usr/local/Cellar/gettext/0.19.7/lib -F/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.2.3/R.framework/.. -framework R -lintl -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
installing to /usr/local/lib/R/3.2/site-library/curl/libs
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/usr/local/lib/R/3.2/site-library/curl/libs/curl.so':
  dlopen(/usr/local/lib/R/3.2/site-library/curl/libs/curl.so, 6): Symbol not found: _curl_easy_cleanup
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/R/3.2/site-library/curl/libs/curl.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /usr/local/lib/R/3.2/site-library/curl/libs/curl.so
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/3.2/site-library/curl’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/8r/_zl3t3w53tj1mnb6bmyb_55c0000gn/T/RtmpUtKNeA/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("curl") :
  installation of package ‘curl’ had non-zero exit status
```

When I type `curl --version` from the terminal, I get `curl 7.43.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin15.0) libcurl/7.43.0 SecureTransport zlib/1.2.5`

I've tried reinstalling xcode, reinstall R, and generally reading every non-zero exit status google post I can find.  Any help would be appreciated.

**Updates**

Found a copy of the previous release curl_0.9.4.tar.gz and tried to install with same error.
Packages such as forecast, lubridate, Hmisc, etc have all installed successfully.

In response to info request:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.2.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.11.2 (El Capitan)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
> .libPaths()
[1] "/usr/local/lib/R/3.2/site-library"                                   
[2] "/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.2.3/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library"
```

Comment: Don't understand the down votes.  If there's any additional information you'd like for me to add, I'm all for it.

Comment: Same problem here. I reinstalled pretty much everything from scratch but it did not help either. Weird thing is that it works perfectly on my laptop that has pretty much the same configuration as my desktop computer on which it refuses to update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I figured it out. I had an old - most likely badly customized - Makevars file that was lying around in my .R folder. It seems that it was essentially overriding all the build options of the package. Once I removed it, all went back to normal and I managed to update curl and devtools. I hope this helps.

Comment: Boom!  Yeah, there was one assignment for gettext in there, but once I deleted that Makevars file, the install went fine.