# R CMD check NOTEs GitHub URL as (possibly) invalid

Tags: r, devtools

I am attempting to release an R package, and like many packages I have the [GitHub page](https://github.com/paulhibbing/TwoRegression) listed in DESCRIPTION and CITATION. The issues page is also listed in DESCRIPTION.

The package passes `devtools::build_win()` and [builds on Travis CI](https://travis-ci.org/paulhibbing/TwoRegression). The only NOTE I get in either of those cases is the one about it being the package's first submission.

But when I run `devtools::release()`, the NOTE includes the following, which is repeated for each instance in which I give a GitHub URL:

> Found the following (possibly) invalid URLs:
>   URL:
>   https://github.com/paulhibbing/TwoRegression
>       From: DESCRIPTION
>       Status: Error
>       Message: libcurl error code 35
>         error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version

Here is my session info:

> R version 3.2.4 Revised (2016-03-16 r70336) Platform:
>   i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit) Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build
>   9200)
>
> locale: [1](https://github.com/paulhibbing/TwoRegression) LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
>   LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    [3] LC_MONETARY=English_United
>   States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                           [5]
>   LC_TIME=English_United States.1252
>
> attached base packages: [1](https://github.com/paulhibbing/TwoRegression) stats     graphics  grDevices utils
>   datasets  methods   base
>
> other attached packages: [1](https://github.com/paulhibbing/TwoRegression) TwoRegression_0.1
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):  [1](https://github.com/paulhibbing/TwoRegression) Rcpp_0.12.10
>   rstudioapi_0.7    xml2_1.1.1        magrittr_1.5      roxygen2_6.0.1
>   [6] devtools_1.12.0   MASS_7.3-45       R6_2.2.2
>   stringr_1.2.0     dplyr_0.5.0       [11] tools_3.2.4
>   data.table_1.10.5 DBI_0.7           withr_2.0.0       commonmark_1.2
>   [16] rprojroot_1.3-2   digest_0.6.12     assertthat_0.2.0 
>   tibble_1.3.0      crayon_1.3.4      [21] tuneR_1.3.2
>   testthat_1.0.2    curl_2.5          signal_0.7-6      seewave_2.0.5
>   [26] memoise_1.1.0     stringi_1.1.5     backports_1.1.1   desc_1.1.1

I have tried updating `curl` from source, but it fails with:

> c:/rtools/gcc-4.6.3/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.6.3/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
>   cannot find -lz collect2: ld returned 1 exit status no DLL was created
>   ERROR: compilation failed for package 'curl'
>   * removing 'C:/Users/Paul/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/curl'
>   * restoring previous 'C:/Users/Paul/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/curl' Warning in install.packages :   running command
>   '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.4RE/bin/i386/R" CMD INSTALL -l
>   "C:\Users\Paul\Documents\R\win-library\3.2"
>   C:\Users\Paul\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpAflnM7/downloaded_packages/curl_3.1.tar.gz'
>   had status 1 Warning in install.packages :   installation of package
>   ‘curl’ had non-zero exit status

I have curl 7.58.0 and OpenSSL 1.1.0f installed on my system, and running `curl -I -L https://github.com/paulhibbing/TwoRegression` gives:

> HTTP/1.1
>   200 OK
>   Server: GitHub.com
>   Date: Sun, 11 Mar 2018 22:07:34 GMT
>   Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8 Status: 200 OK Cache-Control:
>   no-cache Vary: X-PJAX X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1 Set-Cookie:
>   logged_in=no; domain=.github.com; path=/; expires=Thu, 11 Mar 2038
>   22:07:34 -0000; secure; HttpOnly Set-Cookie:
>
> _gh_sess=eyJzZXNzaW9uX2lkIjoiODc0MWFkMDU3Y2FhMTU0MDdlMTZkZDkyZmQzNGEyMmEiLCJsYXN0X3JlYWRfZnJvbV9yZXBsaWNhcyI6MTUyMDgwNjA1NDE1OSwic3B5X3JlcG8iOiJwYXVsaGliYmluZy9Ud29SZWdyZXNzaW9uIiwic3B5X3JlcG9fYXQiOjE1MjA4MDYwNTQsIl9jc3JmX3Rva2VuIjoiS3N2UWhwaWl4c1Q0aTFNellwZEF3bUhZbElhdDlvenVsdFQxSWo1VmtSWT0iLCJmbGFzaCI6eyJkaXNjYXJkIjpbImFuYWx5dGljc19sb2NhdGlvbiJdLCJmbGFzaGVzIjp7ImFuYWx5dGljc19sb2NhdGlvbiI6Ii88dXNlci1uYW1lPi88cmVwby1uYW1lPiJ9fX0%3D--60ed8470ecfccac7fb7187791e4f09f737c1db04;
>   path=/; secure; HttpOnly X-Request-Id:
>   2e7029a9039c25f5ff66f76f9c6d6f59 X-Runtime: 0.214595 Expect-CT:
>   max-age=2592000,
>   report-uri="https://api.github.com/_private/browser/errors"
>   Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'; base-uri 'self';
>   block-all-mixed-content; child-src render.githubusercontent.com;
>   connect-src 'self' uploads.github.com status.github.com
>   collector.githubapp.com api.github.com www.google-analytics.com
>   github-cloud.s3.amazonaws.com
>   github-production-repository-file-5c1aeb.s3.amazonaws.com
>   github-production-upload-manifest-file-7fdce7.s3.amazonaws.com
>   github-production-user-asset-6210df.s3.amazonaws.com
>   wss://live.github.com; font-src assets-cdn.github.com; form-action
>   'self' github.com gist.github.com; frame-ancestors 'none'; img-src
>   'self' data: assets-cdn.github.com identicons.github.com
>   collector.githubapp.com github-cloud.s3.amazonaws.com
>   *.githubusercontent.com; manifest-src 'self'; media-src 'none'; script-src assets-cdn.github.com; style-src 'unsafe-inline'
>   assets-cdn.github.com; worker-src 'self' Strict-Transport-Security:
>   max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains; preload X-Content-Type-Options:
>   nosniff X-Frame-Options: deny X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
>   X-Runtime-rack: 0.222647 X-GitHub-Request-Id:
>   D287:1BDE1:342EA0F:5B4AB8A:5AA5A8A5

So my questions are:
1. Why do I get the NOTE about invalid URLs?
2. If it is an issue with `curl_2.5`, why am I unable to install `curl_3.1` from source?

Comment: Looks like a bug with `curl` and you need to update. How are you trying to update `curl`? You need to use this command: `install.packages("https://github.com/jeroen/curl/archive/master.tar.gz", repos = NULL)`

Comment: Thanks. I had been trying to update with `devtools::install_github()`, but I got a similar error using the command you gave.

That led me to [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35142232/r-devtools-install-error-installation-of-package-curl-had-non-zero-exit-stat) and ultimately to reinstall R, which fixed the problem.

Comment: Nice! Glad I could help.